# c# Regex: Operators, arithmatic operations and numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex I have text like

`O>C1 OR AND and or C>C1`

I need to select only alphabates and alphanumeric while ignoring 
`"OR, AND, and or, all arithmetic operators"`

I am using this regex 
`[OHLVC][\d]|[OHLVC][^AND|OR|and|or]`

it partially full fills the purpose but it's not ignoring arithmetic operators

Comment: What did you try? Where did you run into trouble? If you want me to write one for you, that'll be US$150/hour.

Comment: start here www.nregex.com and then come back when you stuck.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: So, you just need a bunch of alternative classes, something like `(-|\+|\/|\*|>=|<=|>|<|\d+|==|!=|=)`

Comment: how to find only alphabates and alphanumeric using regex?
example
C,C4,C5

Comment: Use this regex for alphabet or alphanumeric [a-z][\d]?

Comment: I am not sure what you need but you could certainly have a look at the word boundaries - [`\b[OHLVC]\d?\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5bOHLVC%5d%5cd%3f%5cb&i=O%3eC1+OR+AND+and+or+C%3eC1)

Answer (score 0):

No one here will do the work for you. Moreover, we will definitely help you if you run into problems and cannot solve the problem you are having.

I would start here:

[http://www.regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) has some good theory.

http://regexstorm.net/ online .net regex tester

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression Wikipedia has some good theory too.

Comment: i think if you just read title of my question you will probably know which language I am using also I have mentioned what I tried which is not the working solution. So I just need some tweaks in my solution. May be I am missing somethin